# for tag in jQuery find method

Tags: jquery

I have to check if an attribute is set true to a `label` where it is mapped to a `radio` button whose value is `abc`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="abc" class="buttonset ui-helper">
<label for="radio1" class="ui-button ui-state-active" role="button" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-text">tesData</span></label>
```

So now, i have the value `abc` and now i have to find if the mapped `label(for="radio1")` is having the attribute `aria-pressed="true"`.

I tried,

```
if ($("input [value=abc]").find('label [for=radio1]').hasClass('aria-pressed'))
{
     //if true do something
}
```

Where can i check if the class value is `true` and how to map the `for` tag for input and label.

Comment: `label[for=radio1]` remove space

Comment: and the same for `input[value=abc]`

Comment: Given that jQuery - and also plain JavaScript, with `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` - uses CSS selectors it might be worth (re-) familiarising yourself with those CSS selectors and the syntax.

Comment: @All: Does this returns the class value or checks the class exist?

Comment: hasClass not return your class it will check class exists or not

Comment: aria-pressed is not a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the following

```js
// use attribute selectors for the label and include the id of the input as the for in the label
// the .length says if there are any present, then do the stuff in your if
if($('label[aria-pressed=true][for=' + $("input[value=abc]").attr('id') + ']').length) {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="abc" class="buttonset ui-helper">
<label for="radio1" class="ui-button ui-state-active" role="button" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-text">tesData</span></label>
```

Comment: Very best solution for which i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`aira-pressed` is not a class but an `attribute`. So instead of using `hasClass('aria-pressed')` try with `attr('aria-pressed')`

```js
if ($("input[value=abc]").next('label[for=radio1]').attr('aria-pressed') == "true")
{
     console.log("works")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="abc" class="buttonset ui-helper">
<label for="radio1" class="ui-button ui-state-active" role="button" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-text">tesData</span></label>
```

For a more Dynamic solution:

`aira-pressed` is not a class but an `attribute`. So instead of using `hasClass('aria-pressed')` try with `attr('aria-pressed')`

```js
$("input[value=abc]").each(function() {
  var lab = $(this).next('label[for="' + $(this).attr("id") + '"');
  if (lab.attr('aria-pressed') == "true") {
    console.log("Label for: " + lab.attr("for") + ", has aria-pressed = true" )
  }
  else {
    console.log("Label for: " + lab.attr("for") + ", has aria-pressed = false" )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="abc" class="buttonset ui-helper">
<label for="radio1" class="ui-button ui-state-active" role="button" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-text">tesData</span></label>

<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="abc" class="buttonset ui-helper">
<label for="radio2" class="ui-button ui-state-active" role="button" aria-pressed="false"><span class="ui-button-text">tesData2</span></label>
```

Comment: How can i map the `label [for=radio1]` since i have many tags like this. I need that to be dynamic which means it should map itself without specifying the id. Is just `next('label')` is enough?

Answer (score 0):

The best dynamic way is.

```js
var input_val="abc";
if ($('label[for="'+$('input[value="'+input_val+'"]').attr('id')+'"]').attr('aria-pressed') == "true")
{
     console.log("it works")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="abc" class="buttonset ui-helper">
<label for="radio1" class="ui-button ui-state-active" role="button" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-text">tesData</span></label>
```